# Swim-lane view in Jira/Greenhopper

Tags: jira, jira-agile

Is it possible to show issues in Jira/Greenhopper in a swim-lane type of view? What I need is a view similar to Greenhopper's Task view with ToDo/In Progress/Done lanes, but with version lanes. For example, I want to see vertical lanes displaying V1/V2/V3 with issues belonging to each version show in appropriate lane?

Perhaps there is a plug-in for that? Ideally, we could configure lanes, so instead of version we could show issues classified by asignee, type, component, custom issue field, etc on a single screen.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Issue Groups Plugin that does this - http://www.aygile.com

Answer (score 1):

It's in an upcoming release - https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-2478

Answer (score 1):

The Rapid board is exactly what you are after, and quite usable as of JIRA 4.4 (which now integrates GreenHopper 5.7 by default).

See http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+the+Rapid+Board

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Rapid Board labs feature. This board is really nice and very flexible.